# can't invoke yarn after installing with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I just got a upgraded my laptop and installed yarn via npm

and for some some reason when I try to invoke `yarn --v` it throws,

```
yarn : File C:\Users\mattj\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

although, when i run `yarn.cmd --v`

it works fine?

is this an issue with path?

Comment: If you Google the error: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/yarn-cannot-be-loaded-running-scripts-disabled That may help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have to do something with powershell 5,

```
 Get-executionPolicy
```

returns restricted

I fixed it by running this in powershell:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

then pressed

```
a
```

and it works